# remove special characters before upload file

Tags: php, string

with the code below I get an image through a form on a html page, make some cuts in it and add another image to it, it's working perfectly.

I'm having problems with special characters in the name of the image that  I got from the html form ...

In short, before you upload, crop images, move them, etc., I must treat their name ... removing blank spaces, remove accents, etc. ..

I tried to use some functions but without success .. Can someone give a help?

Here my code:

```
<?php

require( "./lib/WideImage.php");

// Example of accessing data for a newly uploaded file
$fileName = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]; 
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];
// Path and file name
$pathAndName = "cartelas/cart".$fileName;
// Run the move_uploaded_file() function here
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathAndName);
// Evaluate the value returned from the function if needed


$image = WideImage::load($pathAndName);

$unh = WideImage::load("unh11.png");

$crop1 = $image->crop("25", "50", 111, 132);


$out1 = $crop1->merge($unh,'middle','middle');

$pathAndName1 = "unha-1-".$fileName;

$crop1->saveToFile('./cartelas/estampa'.$pathAndName1);

$out1->saveToFile('./cartelas/'.$pathAndName1);

echo "Imagens geradas:<BR>";
echo "<img src=./cartelas/estampa$pathAndName1><img src=./cartelas/$pathAndName1>";
?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `$newStr = preg_replace("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*/", "_", $str);` That will replace any non-alphanumerics with an underscore.

Answer (score 1):

if u want to do it on php side you can do whatever you want with a filename. If you don't have to have exact same name you can use rawurlencode() or base64_encode(); or even md5() hash from the name. This should solve problems with weird names or special chars.

If u need store all this files u can do `$newfilename = md5($filename) . '_' . uniqid();` so they will be unique. You can add also user id or something like that.

Comment: And what will happen if 2 different files with the SAME name get uploaded at the SAME time?

Answer (score 0):

imclickingmaniac it would lose its extension if you do that! so instead do...

```
<?php
$ext=pathinfo($_FILES["file1"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$fileName=md5($fileName);
$fileName="$fileName.$ext";
?>
```